# Flask context for RQ jobs (RuntimeError: Working outside of application)

Tags: flask, redis, python-rq, rq

First of all, questions about flask_context including context for RQ jobs seems to be common issue but I searched a lot and still couldn't solve my problem.

My decorator functions (tried both of them in different variations):

```
def redis_decorator1(f):
    def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # db interactions
        return res
    return inner_wrapper

def redis_decorator2(app):
    # app.app_context().push()
    def wrapper(f):
        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # db interactions
            return res
        return inner_wrapper
    return wrapper



...
@redis_decorator
def under_decorator_func(*some_args)
```

In function `under_decorator_func`  is used `flask.current_app`.

Problems:

```
First decorator -  RuntimeError: "Working outside of application
context" when redis task starts.

Second decorator - Same error on app start
```

I also tried `app.app_context().push()` right after app is created so I have no idea what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out solution was quite obvious and required a bit more knowledge about python contexts:

```
app = create_app() # or anything that creates your Flask application

...


def redis_decorator2(app):
def wrapper(f):
    def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with app.app_context():
            # db interactions
            return res
    return inner_wrapper
return wrapper
```

Important thing here to use flask context in `inner_wrapper` function and not any layer above, otherwise you will get same error as before.
Hope it will help somebody.